# How to implement PDF Viewer from url in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new to Phonegap. i would like to implement pdf Viewer in phonegap which should work both in android and Ios.I need to show pdf file which comes from a url.Can anyone please help me out in solving this.or else anyone provide any samples

Comment: Do you want to implement a viewer yourself, or are you searching for an existing library/plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the PDF using the **In-App Browser**, using like below:

```
window.open('http://url.com/yourpdf.pdf', '_blank');
```

[Please Refere This Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) for **In-App Browser**

Comment: Hi, I already tried this,which show pdf in external pdf viewer. i am tring to show PDF file With in the  same app.